# MIT Licensed web app - can I enforce copyright header at the top of the main html in derivative works?

Tags: mit, license-recommendation, license-notice

I'm considering releasing a software product under MIT license. It's a complete front-end web application, that users would self-host.

There are 3 parts to the application: index.html (a simple file with some dom structures), app.js (this makes up 95% of the application), and app.css There will be my copyright header in each of these files.

MIT license permits to modify and redistribute the code. Let's say someone wanted to modify and redistribute, but they are using only my app.js (or derivative) and their own custom index.html.

I understand that they would be required to preserve my copyright anywhere near the bundled JavaScript code and there's no doubt about it.

Would they also be required to preserve the copyright header at the top of the HTML file? (the license mentions all copies or substantial portions of the software).

This JavaScript code is not just a library, but the application itself. I think it should be most fair to also preserve the original copyright at the top of the main HTML document (where it's most visible), even if the main HTML isn't a derivative, but is it enforceable?

If not, are there other licenses which I could use to accomplish this, or would I have to create my own license (e.g. by adding an additional clause to MIT License)